# magento get state drop down custom form frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

how to get custom drop down state in magento save custom form

```
<select name="state" id="state" class="inputreq" flags="2267742732416" type="select-one" valuewhenrendered="">
        <option value="" selected="">State*</option>
        <option value="0">Alabama</option>
        <option value="1">Alaska</option>
        <option value="101">Alberta</option>
        <option value="2">Arizona</option>
        <option value="3">Arkansas</option>
        <option value="53">Armed Forces Americas</option>
        <option value="52">Armed Forces Europe</option>
        <option value="54">Armed Forces Pacific</option>
        <option value="102">British Columbia</option>
        <option value="4">California</option>
        <option value="5">Colorado</option>
        <option value="6">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="7">Delaware</option>
        <option value="8">District of Columbia</option>
        <option value="9">Florida</option>
        <option value="10">Georgia</option>
        <option value="11">Hawaii</option>
        <option value="12">Idaho</option>
        <option value="13">Illinois</option>
        <option value="14">Indiana</option>
        <option value="15">Iowa</option>
        <option value="16">Kansas</option>
        <option value="17">Kentucky</option>
        <option value="18">Louisiana</option>
        <option value="19">Maine</option>
        <option value="103">Manitoba</option>
        <option value="20">Maryland</option>
        <option value="21">Massachusetts</option>
        <option value="22">Michigan</option>
        <option value="23">Minnesota</option>
        <option value="24">Mississippi</option>
        <option value="25">Missouri</option>
        <option value="26">Montana</option>
        <option value="27">Nebraska</option>
        <option value="28">Nevada</option>
        <option value="104">New Brunswick</option>
        <option value="29">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="30">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="31">New Mexico</option>
        <option value="32">New York</option>
        <option value="105">Newfoundland</option>
        <option value="33">North Carolina</option>
        <option value="34">North Dakota</option>
        <option value="107">Northwest Territories</option>
        <option value="106">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option value="108">Nunavut</option>
        <option value="35">Ohio</option>
        <option value="36">Oklahoma</option>
        <option value="109">Ontario</option>
        <option value="37">Oregon</option>
        <option value="38">Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value="110">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option value="39">Puerto Rico</option>
        <option value="111">Quebec</option>
        <option value="40">Rhode Island</option>
        <option value="112">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option value="41">South Carolina</option>
        <option value="42">South Dakota</option>
        <option value="43">Tennessee</option>
        <option value="44">Texas</option>
        <option value="45">Utah</option>
        <option value="46">Vermont</option>
        <option value="47">Virginia</option>
        <option value="48">Washington</option>
        <option value="49">West Virginia</option>
        <option value="50">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="51">Wyoming</option>
        <option value="113">Yukon</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$statearray = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter("US")->load();
if(count($statearray) > 0){
?>
    <select name='state'>
    <option value=''>--Please Select--</option>
    <?php foreach ($statearray as $_state) {?>
        <option value='<?php echo $_state->getCode();?>'><?php echo $_state->getDefaultName();?></option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
<?php }?>
```

Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: magento 1.9 use custom state dropdwon

Comment: @Ravindrasinh Zala Please check my updated ans.

Comment: but how to use select box in html

Comment: @Ravindrasinh Zala Please check my ans.

Comment: now i have one question how to pass us and ca miss canada

Comment: us and ca both code how to use

Comment: I have no more idea But you can also load both collection separate then merge both collection, finally you can use any where when you use.

Comment: $statearrayus = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter("US")->load();
$statearrayca = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->getResourceCollection()->addCountryFilter("CA")->load();

merge $statearrayus and  $statearrayca

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76889/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-vithal-bariya).